# Replace hyphen with empty string in specific column of csv

Tags: shell

I have a csv file with 30 columns. I need to remove hyphen only from the 30th column.(3rd and 4th column contains hyphen but it should not be removed.)I tried below awk command to achieve it. But it is removing few records and I couldn't find the reason.

```
awk -f=',' 'gsub= "\\-","",$30)' OFS=, input.csv > output.csv
```

Please suggest a solution to remove hyphens in specific column of csv without removing records.

PFB the sample input:

```
roll,name,type
01,j-man,re-open
01,i-man,reopen
01,j-man,reopen
01,r-man,re-open
```

expected output:

```
roll,name,type
01,j-man,reopen
01,i-man,reopen
01,j-man,reopen
01,r-man,reopen
```

Comment: put a minimal fragment of your `input.csv`

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: try $(30) instead of $30

Answer (score 0):

I used the example to illustrate with 10th column. Replace 10 with 30 for your case

```
$ cat > hyphen.txt
roll,name,type,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11
01-1,j-man,re-open,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,ab--cd,r11
01-2,i-man,reopen,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,pq--rs,r11
01-3,j-man,reopen,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11
01-4,r-man,re-open,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11


$ awk -F"," -v OFS=, ' { gsub(/[-]/,"",$10); print } ' hyphen.txt
roll,name,type,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11
01-1 j-man re-open r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 r9 abcd r11
01-2 i-man reopen r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 r9 pqrs r11
01-3,j-man,reopen,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11
01-4,r-man,re-open,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,r11
```